# How to auto-number quote line items 1,2,3... but for each quote?

Tags: formula, formula-field, quotelineitem, auto-number, quote-template

When I create a quote with say 3 items surely these items appear enumerated as 1,2,3. But then when you create a new quote it keeps going to 4,5,6...

Does anyone know how to create a custom flied that would prevent this from happening?